# mysql "upsert" query on table with two different unique columns

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to write a MySQL query to "upsert" into the following table:

```
ID (auto_int) | Code (unique) | Name (unique) | LastMod | LastBy | Other fields
========================================================================
1             | Code1         | Name1         |2015-2-2 |'system'|...
2             | Code2         | Name3         |2015-2-17|'system'|...
```

1. if code and name doesn't exist, insert
2. if code or (exclusive) name exist, update that name/code to match on duplicate
3. if code and name exist, in the same row, update "other" fields
4. if code and name exist, but in different rows, do nothing (detect as error in C#)
5. I need to select the row (with ID) that was inserted/updated (#4 can be handled here in C# by returning "0" rows and seeing that as an "error")
6. If any of the SQL in the transaction throws an error, roll back (I'm hoping it does this as is, but I want to confirm this is the case).

I come from an SqlServer back ground and I'm having a REALLY hard time not using If statements.

This needs to be a block of SQL (not a function/SP) and ideally transaction safe.  (Has START TRANSACTION;/COMMIT;)

I've started at:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET @lastModified = '2015-02-18 22:21:51';
SET @Code = 'code4';
SET @Name = 'name4';
SET @ModifiedBy = 'system';
UPDATE test1.catalog SET LastModified = @lastModified, ModifiedBy = @ModifiedBy WHERE Code = @Code AND Name = @Name;
INSERT IGNORE INTO test1.catalog (LastModified, ModifiedBy, Code, Name) VALUES (@lastModified, @modifiedBy, @code, @name);
#???
SELECT * FROM test1.catalog WHERE name = @name AND code = @code;
COMMIT;
```

Thanks!

Comment: MySQL supports if statements http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

Comment: If as flow control is only supported in procedures and triggers in MySQL